# Copy active field configuration in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, fields-attributes

I am working with ArcGIS Pro 2.9.
I have a map with several layers that point to the same source. I want to know how to copy the active field configuration from one layer to the others, because there are many many fields and checking the same configuration takes a lot of time and manual checking is very prone to error.

Comment: I have Arcmap script which does that. To use it you need to know a) how to attach it to tool in toolbox b) Python experience and c) how to tweak few lines to make it work in Pro. Do you have this knowledge?

Comment: I have done those things in ArcPy for ArcMap, I can certaintly try. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is script:

```py
##  SHOW/HIDE FIELDS NOT IN LAYOUT
##
try: arcpy
except: import arcpy
layoutFC=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
destFC=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
invert=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
newName=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

sourceFields=arcpy.ListFields(layoutFC)
destFields=arcpy.ListFields(destFC)
if invert=="VISIBLE":
    sourceNames=[row.aliasName for row in sourceFields]
    destNames=[row.aliasName for row in destFields]
else:
    sourceNames=[row.name for row in sourceFields]
    destNames=[row.name for row in destFields]

desc = arcpy.Describe(destFC)
field_info = desc.fieldInfo

rest=set(destNames).difference(set(sourceNames))

if invert=="HIDDEN":
    for i,f in enumerate(destFields):
        if f.name not in rest: field_info.setVisible (i, "HIDDEN")
        field_info.setNewName (i, f.name)
else:
    for i,f in enumerate(destFields):
        if f.aliasName in rest: field_info.setVisible (i, "HIDDEN")
        field_info.setNewName (i, f.name)
theSource=arcpy.mapping.Layer(destFC).dataSource
arcpy.AddMessage(theSource)

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
addLayer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(theSource, newName,"","",field_info).getOutput(0)
##addLayer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(destFC, newName,"","",field_info).getOutput(0)
addLayer.visible = False
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "TOP")

del mxd, addLayer
```

Interface:

[image]

Parameter of interest:

[image]

Comment: Thanks FelixP, I will post it in Arcpy Pro version when I finish it.